# Total word count in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, creative-cloud

Is this possible? it seems I can only get a word count when specifically highlighting text.

Is it possible to get the total word count for all of the text in an ID document?

Comment: I don’t think there is, out of the box, but I’m also not sure how it would even work in an application like InDesign. What should count as “all of the text”? If you have parent page content on each page, should that be counted once for every page, just once for the parent page, or not at all? How about text on the pasteboard? Hidden or conditional text?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Good point! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround is to use the built-in "Export All Stories" script, which generates TXT or RTF files for every story in the document. Then use Word or Google Docs to import these files and use their built-in word count features.

Caution, **this plugin will generate a TXT or RTF file for every unthreaded story** in your INDD doc, which means if the INDD doc is broken up into many text boxes, you will get many TXT or RTF files to work with.

[image]